# Does an adapter from "disk bay" to 3.5" exist?

Tags: hard-drive, optical-drive, case, case-mods

I bought a new HDD, but without the foresight of checking if I even had physical space in my case.

There is some, but only above the optical reader. However those bays are way larger than the HDD, naturally. Does an adapter/support/bracket exist that allows me to put my HDD in place of a disk reader slot.

Or do I have to either ditch one of the old drives or get a new case?

Comment: 5.25" to 3.5" adapter exist. Can you confirm what "disk bay" you means? Is it the same physical size as the CD/DVD Drive bay (which is commonly 5.25" in size)? The term you need to google is 5.25" to 3.5" Adapter

Comment: @Darius Thanks, yes, I meant the CD/DVD drive bays.

Comment: And your new drive is a "3.5 inch" size? (They're not really 3.5 inch, but that's what they're called.) If so, Google for these words: { 3.5 5.25 adapter } There are many available. You may need a Molex-to-SATA power adapter as well.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Yeah, "3.5". But apparently these adapters are nowhere to be found in Brazil :/ (I see them on the US Amazon, but after checking a bunch of national stores, none had any)

Comment: @Kroltan ebay, or try us ebay or us amazon and ask a seller if they can post it to you